# How to populate a matrix based on criteria for rows and columns (Updated 2x)

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

**Updated 2x** I have checked the issue and now I can give a better explanation.

I am trying to do a schedule planning using [r](/questions/tagged/r). My issue is explained next.

I have a set of **n** workers and they need to work during a period of **m** months (aka **p**). The only conditions that need to be satisfied are next:

Each day is always required that **np** workers need to be working in the factory.
All the workers must have **r=8** days of rest per month but each day there must always be **np** people working.

Those are the conditions that need to be completed for this issue. In this way I think I could use the days of month to populate the days of working but I am not sure on how to set the rest days such that each month each worker only must have 8 days of rest. I would set a matrix with an example of 12 workers during two months. The only conditions are: each day **np=8** workers must be in the factory and every month they can only have **r=8** days of rest.

I have a code like this:

```
#Workers
n <- 12;
#Months (Days)
p <- 59;
#Number of people required each day
np <- 8;
#Rest days per month
r <- 8
#Matrix
#Days
vday <- seq(as.Date('2023-02-01'),as.Date('2023-03-31'),by=1)
mm <- matrix(data =NA,nrow = n,ncol = length(vday))
dimnames(mm)[[2]]<-as.character(vday)
```

But it is complex for me finding a way so that I have **np=8** persons working each day and that each month each of them must rest only **r=8** days per month but keeping the condition that each day are needed **np** people in the factory. Resting days could be allocated random each month taking into acount the condition. I would set 1 for working and 0 for resting.

Comment: This question seems to be turning into a chameleon. With this newest iteration there are again some ambiguities. "*each worker only must have 8 days of rest*" sounds like they can have neither more nor less. For this to work, `r` has to be a minimum. You should say that explicitly. Is `p` months or days? Probably days, but again, ambiguous.

Comment: But finally and most importantly, the most straightforward way to solve this current iteration is to have a first group of 8 work for 8 days, then switch 4, have them work for 8 days, then switch the last 4 and keep them for the month. I get the impression that such an answer would make you realize that you care about the distribution of rest days across the month and the distribution of work load across the workers, leading to another moving of the goal posts. Thus, I will not make another attempt at an answer. If I could vote to close a bountied question for clarity reasons, I would.

Comment: @shs I believe I have explained at more detail. If you do not want to help is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it remains unclear what should happen when there are not enough rested workers to fill a full team for the day, this solution assumes there are always enough workers for a rested team to be available every day. It simply rotates through the workers.

```r
library(tidyverse)
n <- 15; p <- 15; np <- 7; k <- 2; r <- 2

sol <- rep(c(integer(k-1), 1), length.out = p-1) |> # Vector of days, 1 for rotation, 0 for same crew
  accumulate(
    .f = \(lhs, rhs) {if (rhs) {c(tail(lhs, np), head(lhs, n-np))} else {lhs}}, # move last np elements to the front of the vector
    .init = c(rep(1L, np), rep(0L, n-np))  # init vector
  ) %>%
  set_names(str_c("D", seq_along(.))) %>% 
  c(list(Workers = seq_len(n)), .) |> # Add workers col
  do.call(what = cbind)

sol
#>       Workers D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 D10 D11 D12 D13 D14 D15
#>  [1,]       1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
#>  [2,]       2  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
#>  [3,]       3  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
#>  [4,]       4  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
#>  [5,]       5  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   0   0   1
#>  [6,]       6  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
#>  [7,]       7  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
#>  [8,]       8  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
#>  [9,]       9  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
#> [10,]      10  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
#> [11,]      11  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
#> [12,]      12  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   0
#> [13,]      13  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   0   0   1   1   0
#> [14,]      14  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
#> [15,]      15  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
```

If you care about the distinction between resting `0` and rested non-working `NA`, you can add that like such:

```r
sol[, -1] <- sol[, -1] |> 
  apply(1, \(x) ifelse((cumsum(x==0) %>% {. - lag(., r+1, 0)})>r, NA_integer_, x)) |> 
  t()
sol
#>       Workers D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 D10 D11 D12 D13 D14 D15
#>  [1,]       1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
#>  [2,]       2  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
#>  [3,]       3  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
#>  [4,]       4  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
#>  [5,]       5  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0  NA  NA   1
#>  [6,]       6  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0 NA  NA   1   1   0   0   1
#>  [7,]       7  1  1  0  0 NA NA  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
#>  [8,]       8  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
#>  [9,]       9  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
#> [10,]      10  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
#> [11,]      11  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
#> [12,]      12  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0  NA
#> [13,]      13  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0  NA  NA   1   1   0
#> [14,]      14  0  0  1  1  0  0 NA NA  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
#> [15,]      15  0  0 NA NA  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
```

Comment: Many thanks. This solution works for the example but when I extend to more days like `n <- 12; p <- 333; np <- 8; k <- 5; r <- 2` produces messy results. For example, that output shows that first workers work during 10 continuous days and rest for 5 continuous days. That is not correct, I need that all workers, first 8 of them for 5 days and rest 2. Then, the remaining 4 for plus 4 that have worked and rested do the same. If you could change the code for this, it would be great! Many thanks!

Comment: I had asked asked you about this situation, and you did not answer the question, just said that there *must* always be `np` workers working. That is why I wrote in my answer that it is assumed that there are always enough rested workers available. You need to state your expectations clearly, or else you are just wasting the time of people trying to help you

Comment: So to make it clear: Am I correct in interpreting your comment such that on days when there are not at least `np` rested workers available, no one works?

Comment: Many thanks. There will always be more workers than number of persons needed to work. For example, I always have 12 workers, and I always need to have 8 of them working for five continuous days and resting 2 days. Once the eight persons have worked 5 days and rested 2, then the remaining 4 will start to work 5 and rest 2. As I need 4 more to complete 8, then from the initial 8, I will take 4 of them that have worked 5 and have rested 2. I need that all days there are 8 persons working otherwise the service could not be done.

Comment: If is not clear yet, let me know so that I can explain better. I need that all days 8 persons are working. Once they work for 5 days, they have to rest 2 days.

Comment: In your example, on the 6th day, 8 of your 12 workers must rest for 2 days. Thus, you have only 4 rested workers available that day. You cannot have a team of 8 rested workers working that day. It is impossible to fulfill all your conditions unless `n >= 2*np`

Comment: You are right, so your logic is correct!

Comment: I have updated the issue after checking the problem properly. Sorry for the time you invested. I hope you can help this time! Kind regards!

Comment: I have awarded you the bounty to avoid wasting points and as I think you did more effort to solve the issue. Could not find a way to solve it yet, but thanks for contributing. Sorry for not being clear!

Comment: Thanks, wasn't expecting that. Let me give you some last advice: You should revert the question to the state before your last edit. That last edit was actually against the rules of SO. It is considered vandalism to fundamentally change a question like that, as the answers no longer relate to the question. I get why you did it. Spending 1/4 of your rep is a lot. That's why I did not force the issue. Now that the bounty is gone, revert it and post a new question with the revised problem. Clear up the ambiguities I mentioned and be as specific as you can. That might get you your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are naming the variables is misleading as `np` looks to me as a multiplication. I propose a function that can deal with your problem with a different variable naming.

This function returns an error in two cases:

- The total number of workers you consider is not integer-divisible for the number of working groups you need. So if you need 2 groups the total number of workers must be integer-divisible by 2 (2, 4, 8, ..., 14). It could accommodate non-integer division but the coding gets a bit more complex and you should specify what you want to do with the extra workers.
- The work-rest schedule is not feasible with the number of groups you plan to use. For instance a 2-day work/3-day rest schedule is not possible having 2 groups of workers (unless nobody work on certain days).

If no error occurs then the function returns a `data.frame` with the following characteristics:

1. Column one the worker ID
2. Column two the group ID
3. All remaining columns represent the working days and can have the following values: `1` - the worker has to work, `0` - the worker has to rest, `NA` - the worker has neither to work nor rest.

FUNCTION CODE:

```
work_schedule <- function(workers, total_days, group_size, day_streak, rest_days){
  
  if(workers %% group_size != 0){
    stop("workers are not divisible in groups of equal sizes")
  }
  
  n_groups <- workers / group_size
  
  df <- data.frame(worker = seq_len(workers), # NOTE FOR MORE THAN 26 GROUPS THE GROUP NAMING MUST BE CHANGED
                   group = rep(LETTERS[seq_len(n_groups)], each = group_size))
  
  schedule <- matrix(nrow = nrow(df), ncol = total_days)
  
  pttrn <- c(rep(1, day_streak), rep(0, rest_days))
  
  d0 <- 1
  g_names <- unique(df$group)
  g_ind <- 1
  
  while(d0 <= total_days){
    
    d1 <- d0+length(pttrn)-1
    if(d0+length(pttrn)-1 > total_days){
      d1 <- total_days
    }
    
    mt <- t(schedule[df$group == g_names[g_ind], d0:d1])
            
    if( !all(is.na(mt)) ) stop("Not enough groups to comply with working and resting days schedule")
    
    mt[,] <- pttrn[1:length(d0:d1)]
    
    schedule[df$group == g_names[g_ind], d0:d1] <- t(mt)
    
    d0 <- d0 + day_streak
    
    g_ind <- g_ind + 1
    
    if(g_ind > length(g_names)){
      g_ind <- 1
    }
    
  }
    
  colnames(schedule) <- paste0("D", seq_len(total_days))
  return(cbind(df, schedule))
  
}
```

EXAMPLES:

```
# Example 1
work_schedule(12, 15, 3, 2, 2)

   worker group D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 D10 D11 D12 D13 D14 D15
1       1     A  1  1  0  0 NA NA NA NA  1   1   0   0  NA  NA  NA
2       2     A  1  1  0  0 NA NA NA NA  1   1   0   0  NA  NA  NA
3       3     A  1  1  0  0 NA NA NA NA  1   1   0   0  NA  NA  NA
4       4     B NA NA  1  1  0  0 NA NA NA  NA   1   1   0   0  NA
5       5     B NA NA  1  1  0  0 NA NA NA  NA   1   1   0   0  NA
6       6     B NA NA  1  1  0  0 NA NA NA  NA   1   1   0   0  NA
7       7     C NA NA NA NA  1  1  0  0 NA  NA  NA  NA   1   1   0
8       8     C NA NA NA NA  1  1  0  0 NA  NA  NA  NA   1   1   0
9       9     C NA NA NA NA  1  1  0  0 NA  NA  NA  NA   1   1   0
10     10     D NA NA NA NA NA NA  1  1  0   0  NA  NA  NA  NA   1
11     11     D NA NA NA NA NA NA  1  1  0   0  NA  NA  NA  NA   1
12     12     D NA NA NA NA NA NA  1  1  0   0  NA  NA  NA  NA   1


# Example 2
work_schedule(14, 15, 7, 2, 2)

   worker group D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 D10 D11 D12 D13 D14 D15
1       1     A  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
2       2     A  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
3       3     A  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
4       4     A  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
5       5     A  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
6       6     A  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
7       7     A  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   1   0
8       8     B NA NA  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
9       9     B NA NA  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
10     10     B NA NA  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
11     11     B NA NA  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
12     12     B NA NA  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
13     13     B NA NA  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
14     14     B NA NA  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. There was something wrong in the concept. I have updated the logic and required output.

Comment: Many Thanks! Tried `d1 <- work_schedule(workers = 12,total_days = 333,group_size = 8,day_streak = 5,rest_days = 2)` and did not worked!

Comment: I have updated the issue after checking the problem properly. Sorry for the time you invested. I hope you can help this time! Kind regards!